# Arrival and departure on same day to/from India

Tags: indian-citizens, india

I'd like to travel to India from Ireland and back to take my son with me from India. Under the current restrictions, will it be possible to arrive and depart on the same day, provided I am able to get a flight back on the same day of arrival without leaving the airport? I'm planning this as I don't want my wife and new born alone in Ireland for a week or so during my quarantine in India.

**EDIT**

Myself and my son are both Indian citizens. I am a stamp 4 holder in Ireland and had been to India for 3 months for an official trip from October 2020 to January 2021. I had to leave my son with his grand parents for the delivery of my new born as I can't bring anyone from our families due to short stay visa suspensions in Ireland.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer. Without knowing your citizenship, your son's citizenship, where you've both been in the past month, and the itinerary(-ies) of the flights, covid entry and quarantine requirements at your stops and destinations cannot be ascertained. I must add that, for me, few things would be less attractive than back-to-back half-hemisphere flights.

Comment: If your job is remote you could also consider a 1-way trip to India until COVID is over.

Comment: The guidelines have been [revised](https://www.newdelhiairport.in/media/1622/latest-guidelines-for-international-arrivals.pdf) recently. For flights originating from UK, Europe, Middle East or if you have transited those you require negative PCR report before boarding. On arrival you pay for molecular test & if it is negative have to quarantine (home) for 7 days. For short stay the guidelines are not very clear and it looks like passengers who test negative can leave India early but as your flight is from Europe/UK YMMV. Maybe airport authorities can provide updated guidance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over